# Android - Change the text of the positive button of an AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I reuse an AlertDialog box in my android app.

I create a dialog in the onCreateDialog() method and in the onPrepareDialog() method, I try to change the text of the positiveButton using the following code.

```
alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, this.getString(R.string.add), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
          //Handler code
    }
}
```

The onclick listener is getting changed, but the button text is not changed.

Is it a bug in Android or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

One solution is just to force the button to redraw.  For example, a button to cancel a lengthy operation might change to 'OK' on complete, e.g.

```
Button button = progressDialog.getButton(ProgressDialog.BUTTON1);
button.setText("OK");
button.invalidate();
```

Comment: Thanks! Worth noting that if you do this to the buttons of an AlertDialog in onPrepareDialog, as in the question, you don't even need the `invalidate()`. I guess that's probably because the dialog isn't on screen at that point.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {

        case DIALOG_ID:
            return AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle(R.string.contact_groups_add)
    .setView(addView).setPositiveButton(R.string.ok,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                        int whichButton) {

                }
            }).setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                        int whichButton) {
                }
            }).create();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You have this code in onCreateDialog() or in onPrepareDialog() ?

Comment: In none of them. I don't reused those methods of the activity. This code simply shows an alert dialog with the view from addView (inflated prior).

Comment: I understand this code. But my question was different.

I already use onCreateDialog() and onPrepareDialog() functions. I created the dialog in the onCreateDilaog() method but when I try to change the text of the positive button in the onPrepareDialog() it is only changing the onClickListener and not the text.

Comment: You can easily adapt my example to your needs. Just call `.create();` instead of `show()` and return in your `onCreateDialog` method the `Dialog` created by the code.

Comment: My onCreateDialog() code works properly without any issues. My problem is that, when I try to change the text of the positive button in the onPrepareDialog() using the setButton() method, the text is not changed.

The reason why I am doing it in onPreapareDialog() is that onCreateDialog() will be called only once when the dialog is created for the first time.

I want to reuse the same dialog, but only change the text of the positive button from "Add" to "Edit". When I set the text using the setButton method, it is not getting changed.